# Docker install failed with "computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-V"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

I’ve downloaded Docker in my PC, but it is not installing as I’m getting some errors.

```
ERROR WITH PRE-CREATE CHECK - this computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-V enabled.
Enabling it in BIOS is mandatory.
```

I’ve already enabled Virtualization in BIOS and checked in Task Manager -> CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. Running this in cmd will help you out:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory=4096 --virtualbox-cpu-count=4 --virtualbox-disk-size=40960 --virtualbox-no-vtx-check default
```